# Jquery wrapping the last two items in a menu based on width

Tags: jquery

OK so I want to change the contents of the nav menu based on the width, if it's 720px (for tablet) the menu will get the last two items and put them in a dropdown menu.

Here's my code

```
if($('.topNavigation').css('width','720px')){
    $('.topNavigation ul').slice(-2).wrapAll(function(){
        return '<li><a href="#" class="moreNavItem">More</a><ul>' + $(this) + "</ul></li>";
})
}
```

So that doesn't quite work, it just assigns the menu a width and doesn't wrap the items properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: condition in if is always TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test whether width is 720px, you should write

```
if($('.topNavigation').css('width') == '720px') {
    $('.topNavigation ul').slice(-2).wrapall('<li><a href="#" lass="moreNavItem">More</a><ul></ul></li>')
}
```

As with many jQuery attribute functions, giving one argument retrieves the value, two arguments sets the value.

EDIT: Add wrappall code

Comment: Yeah I did that, it works better but it wraps the last two items individually instead of as one! So close but I'm unsure how to fix it!

Comment: See edited answer. jQuery documentation doesn't say anything about .wrappall allowing a callback function, just give it an HTML snippet.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, now it's inserting all in one wrap but in the wrong area, it inserts in the a tag. I tried inserting the items into just the ul first then prepending the a tag afterwards, but it just seems to ignore the prepend function...

Comment: I was afraid that was going to happen. Can you post a fiddle, we should be able to tweak it.

Comment: OK so I updated it, since this is for tablet I included window.orientation in my code.


`var dynamicMenu = function(){`

  `moreNavItem = '<a href="#" id="moreNavItem">More</a>';`

  `if( window.orientation == 0 ){`
 
    `$('.toplevel').slice(-2).wrapAll('<li id="moreNavLi"><ul class="offsetFix moreNavUl"></ul></li>');`
    `$(moreNavItem).insertBefore($('.moreNavUl'));`
       `} else if( window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90 ){`            `(moreNavItem).hide();`
`$('#moreNavLi > *').unwrap();`
 `}`
`}`

`$(window).load( function() {`
        `dynamicMenu()`
  `});`

Comment: I added a class for each menu item, called toplevel. 

Yet now it won't update the new menu when changing the orientation, it only does so after refreshing the page. It also keeps inserting multiple moreNavItem elements when in portrait mode. I know why this is but running out of ideas of an alternative. Gosh darn tablets :/

Comment: 1. Maybe there's an event that fires when changing orientation, you can run dynamicMenu on that event. 2. Set a variable saying whether you've added the moreNavItems, and don't add it again. BTW, long JavaScript in a comment is unreadable, it would be better to edit the question.

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the late reply. I am no longer using this function, it became too troublesome in the end. Thanks for all the help though :)